Errors and criticals during upgrade of a staging branch
I'm trying to migrate an Odoo database with a lot of custom modules from version 15 to 17. I followed the different steps from odoo's doc but I now think there are issues when the "upgrading a staging branch" process runs.
Here's what I'm doing : I have a staging db that I upgrade. At the end of the 15ish min process, I try pushing an empty commit, the db state is displayed as Failed a few seconds later. Then I try pushing the new version of the modules that I developped and tested on Development branches, but the db state just becomes "Killed" and I get no error message.
So my first question is : am I doing things in the right order ?
And secondly, when I check the logs of the upgrade process, I see a bunch of WARNING lines, as well as ERROR and CRITICAL lines. Should the upgrade process of the Staging branch only be considered successfull is there are no errors at all in the log file ?
Here are the two CRITICALS I get :
CRITICAL db_1877390 odoo.addons.base.maintenance.migrations.base.pre-models-ir_ui_view: It looks like you forgot to call util.remove_view(cr, "l10n_be_reports.res_partner_view_form_inherit_sms")`

CRITICAL db_1877390 odoo.upgrade.util: The field bank.rec.widget.journal_default_account_id is being deleted. Either you forgot to call "util.remove_field", either it is a custom field marked as coming from a standard module due to odoo/odoo#49354.

Also, the ERRORS indicate that none of the custom modules are installed during the upgrade process.
